# Subreport inside another subreport only print the first item of list of object

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans, subreport

i'm trying to work using master report with a subreport, and this one with a subreport too.
I have an a list of Object and i am passing it as a parameter from JAVA.
When i print the Jaspers, only the first item in the list is printed, and i don't know why ( if i only use Master with ONE subreport, it print all the objects and display all the data correctly ).

The code is:
**JAVA** (the most relevant part)

```
Map<String, Object> parametrosTomaMuestra = new HashMap<>();
List<ObjectA> muestras = tomaMuestras.getMuestras();
List<JasperPrint> printList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
parametrosTomaMuestra.put("subReportTomaMuestra", pathReport);
parametrosTomaMuestra.put("muestras", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(muestras));
try {
    JasperReport apdoTomaMuestras = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(pathReport + "/apdoTomaMuestras.jasper");
    printList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport(apdoTomaMuestras, parametrosTomaMuestra, new JREmptyDataSource()));
} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**MASTER JRXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="apdoTomaMuestras" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="13a4a96f-ef00-4573-b951-f01c73cb0d60">
    <parameter name="muestras" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="subReportTomaMuestra" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="258" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="20" y="30" width="505" height="228" uuid="eb89d398-4435-49ad-a886-9f1a3ad76e79"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subReportTomaMuestra">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportTomaMuestra}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{muestras}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportTomaMuestra} + "tomaMuestra.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**SUBREPORT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="tomaMuestra3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="70bd6c22-e031-45e8-9ba6-d46b8f4bb20f">
    <parameter name="subReportTomaMuestra" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="codigo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="446" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="130" width="68" height="20" uuid="e9d20cf5-abd3-4b2a-bd13-5bb2eee4957f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Origen:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="130" width="100" height="20" uuid="aa8869c6-af16-4376-930b-387a88c9bc62"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{origen}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="100" width="100" height="16" uuid="1682066d-193c-4df6-b0fd-305ccd9676f2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{codigo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="100" width="108" height="16" forecolor="#092382" uuid="519eb0f2-e970-4b94-925b-91d5f0aa21d4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Toma de muestra:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="2" y="272" width="550" height="174" uuid="ccbbe4cf-52e6-4551-98b1-c3f397f21b65"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subReportMuestraOrigenA">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportTomaMuestra}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportTomaMuestra} + "muestraOrigenA.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**SUB SUBREPORT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="muestraOrigenA" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Error" uuid="aa7ff2e8-0339-46e8-afde-9b1d5f79c82d">
    <parameter name="muestras" class="es.sigma.imina.modelo.tomamuestras.Muestra"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="afeccionesDescFoco" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="afeccionesOrigenAguasSup" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="afeccionesOrigen" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ph" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="conductividadElectrica" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="446" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="23" width="155" height="20" uuid="28affa9e-e432-4752-82bc-4839d90a914c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Origen de aguas superficiales:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="23" width="44" height="20" uuid="5f8d6af0-fae0-4801-8f36-555da13637fb"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Origen:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="43" width="155" height="20" uuid="745ca6b1-c1f7-41bd-b1c8-d8eb1b9e7a66"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Descripción del foco:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="113" width="251" height="20" forecolor="#092382" uuid="ee62758c-d8be-464b-8b2f-23397b2611f3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[En campo (mediante sondas)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="173" width="130" height="20" uuid="b34814e6-17bb-4a44-921e-b896e5a4ec8a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Conductividad eléctrica:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="143" width="251" height="20" forecolor="#092382" uuid="af2f22f5-2b31-46ef-92d6-82a1b53bef0d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[En laboratorio]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="27" y="173" width="103" height="18" uuid="068d1149-53e9-4490-8502-5d8a4f83ecb3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ph}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="324" y="23" width="126" height="20" uuid="f812038f-0b6c-49c2-86be-0ebb72cf5197"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{afeccionesOrigen}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="63" width="550" height="40" uuid="b9cc8d83-8ec1-40bf-9029-e17998768fad"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{afeccionesDescFoco}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="410" y="173" width="100" height="20" uuid="4c30bbb1-9d66-4673-86ad-5765d8c6cc3c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{conductividadElectrica}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="155" y="23" width="125" height="20" uuid="b2a52619-5ac6-4884-b0fa-88f772cf68d3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{afeccionesOrigenAguasSup}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="173" width="25" height="20" uuid="db0290ba-f224-4a9e-8a3e-1c87e611324b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Noto Sans HK Black" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PH:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Please, ignore the simple desing for the jrxml, i just remove the not relevant information for not do this so long.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your "SUBREPORT" this is not correct:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Since `$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}` is never set, there's no datasource for the "SUB SUBREPORT"

Comment: Hi, yes, i removed that line. i still trying to make this work.
I think that the key is the dataSourceExpression that i pass from subreport to the sub sub report, but i don't know what the solution can be

Comment: Your subreport should have a parameter to type datasource, and this parameter should be set into the dataSourceExpression (so the datasource is passed to the sub sub report)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it passing an new **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()** Datasource Expresion from Subreport to sub sub report  !